# Learning Roadmap for 3-dimensional Hyperbolic Geometry

Tags: reference-request, geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, low-dimensional-topology, teichmueller-theory

I am interested in learning Teichmuller theory. Previously, I learnt 2 dimensional hyperbolic geometry from S. Katok's book. Now, I am interested in learning about significance of hyperbolic geometry in low dimensional geometry, i.e.  Hyperbolic surfaces and their Teichmuller spaces. But I found that to learn Teichmuller theory one should learn some 3- dimensional hyperbolic geometry first. I want to know about what is 3- dimensional hyperbolic geometry.

How should I learn it (3- dimensional hyperbolic geometry)? Which books/ papers I should follow?  Is the subject connected to Teichmuller theory?

Comment: "to learn Teichmuller theory one should learn some 3- dimensional hyperbolic geometry first" is simply false.

Comment: Your roadmap will depend on where do you want to go in the field of hyperbolic geometry. Most textbooks on your list [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4091614/references-on-hyperbolic-geometry-and-teichmuller-theory) would be beneficial. My suggestion, is to find a real advisor who would point you in the right direction, aiming for a specific research project. If you cannot find one, my suggestion would be #7 on your list, just keep in mind that many proofs are sketchy (but at this point, you should be aiming for getting a "big picture").